# Website dumps encoded result

Tags: plugins, encoding

So for some reason i get this result on my website 
[image]

By reading other questions and searching the web i found that something like this could have been a result of some caching plug-in that interferes with something else and thats how we get this result but i don't use any caching plug-in.

Some facts are that:

- The page does use the `charset="utf-8"` meta tag
- The website uses English and Greek characters ( if the problem was one of these first 2 points then the admin panel would also fail , right ? )
- If i log into as admin then the page loads fine.
- I also noticed that if i activate/deactivate any plug-in the website loads once and then after refresh the problem comes up again.

How can i come down to a conclusion of why this is happening?

Did you ever had a similar experience?

What other info should i share so that we find the root of the issue ?

Comment: Deactivate all plugins, activate a default theme and see what happens. If it's still a mess, check database settings (contact your hosting provider if you don't know where to find them). If not, get themes and plugins up one by one until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

So my previous search results were actually true. This problem was coming because of a cache plug-in.

I am hosting this website at BlueHost and there was a plug-in named endurance-page-cache that was installed  by BlueHost to improve the page speed and i was not aware of.From my search i found out that other people where also having problem with this plug-in.

All in all the caching of this plug-in was messing with my website... so i had to talk with BlueHost support so that they will disable the plug-in.
After that the page was working fine.